# Averaging a list of c# object in f#, what is wrong with my syntax

Tags: f#

I have a list of C# objects called `Candle` (it's stock market data) and I need to average a few of these objects into a single one.

The objects are very simple, they just contain a field float fields (`Bid`, `Ask`, `Bidvolume`, `Askvolume`)

I wrote this code, but I don't understand why it doesn't compile:

```
            let zero = new Candle()
            let avg =   entries
                        |> List.fold (fun acc elem ->
                                (
                                    Ask = acc.Ask + elem.Ask,
                                    Bid = acc.Bid + elem.Bid,
                                    AskVolume = acc.AskVolume + elem.AskVolume,
                                    BidVolume = acc.BidVolume + elem.BidVolume
                                )
                            ) zero
                        |>
                            (
                                TimeStamp = time,
                                Ask = Ask / entries.Count,
                                Bid = Bid / entries.Count,
                                AskVolume = AskVolume / entries.Count,
                                BidVolume = BidVolume / entries.count,
                                Integrity = entries.Count / expectedCount
                            )
```

I get the following errors:

```
  BooksCandle.fs(154, 41): [FS0039] The value or constructor 'Ask' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(154, 51): [FS0039] The field, constructor or member 'Ask' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(155, 41): [FS0039] The value or constructor 'Bid' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:   id
  BooksCandle.fs(155, 51): [FS0039] The field, constructor or member 'Bid' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(156, 41): [FS0039] The value or constructor 'AskVolume' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(156, 57): [FS0039] The field, constructor or member 'AskVolume' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(157, 41): [FS0039] The value or constructor 'BidVolume' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(157, 57): [FS0039] The field, constructor or member 'BidVolume' is not defined.
  BooksCandle.fs(159, 35): [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type    'bool * bool * bool * bool'    but here has type    'Candle'
  BooksCandle.fs(162, 37): [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type    'bool * bool * bool * bool -> 'a'    but here has type    ''b * 'c * 'd * 'e * 'f * 'g'
  BooksCandle.fs(170, 22): [FS0039] The value or constructor 'A' is not defined.
```

So, so I guess the object I'm manipulating is not seen as a `Candle`, but using `fun (acc : Candle) (elem : Candle)` doesn't help at all.

Comment: Ask, Bid, etc. where are they defined. You'd need a `let` to bind to them. Also, maybe you can use AverageBy (not sure if its fits your logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#, objects and records are different things. You can create a record value like this:

```
{ Foo = "apple"; Bar = "banana" }
```

But you cannot use the similar syntax for object creation. The code below does not compile:

```
( Foo = "apple", Bar = "banana" )
```

Because it will be understood as:

- a tuple of 2 components, because it is in the form `( component1, component2 )`.
- each component is a bool value, because there is a comparison `=`.
- `Foo` is expected as a value of name `Foo`, but here there is no such a thing. Similar for `Bar`.

Instead, you have to write: `new MyClass ( Foo = "apple", Bar = "banana" )`

I would like to rewrite your code as below:

```
let zero = new Candle ()
let sum =
    entries
    |> List.fold
        (fun acc elem ->
            new Candle (
                Ask = acc.Ask + elem.Ask,
                Bid = acc.Bid + elem.Bid,
                AskVolume = acc.AskVolume + elem.AskVolume,
                BidVolume = acc.BidVolume + elem.BidVolume
            )
        )
        zero
let avg = new Candle (
    TimeStamp = time,
    Ask = sum.Ask / float entries.Length,
    Bid = sum.Bid / float entries.Length,
    AskVolume = sum.AskVolume / float entries.Length,
    BidVolume = sum.BidVolume / float entries.Length,
    Integrity = float entries.Length / float expectedCount
)
```

Note that F# type system is very restricted, so we have to explicitly convert integers to floats.

Comment: This worked, but it spawned another question: entries.Count doesn't work, but entries.Count() does. However putting 'float entries.Count()' doesn't work but doing 'let countf = entries.Count()' and then using countf works. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I forgot that `entries` belongs to type [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list%5b%27t%5d-union-%5bfsharp%5d) thus we have to use `entries.Length` (a property) not `entries.Count` (a property) or `entries.Count()` (a method). I have no idea why `entries.Count()` is valid in your environment. However, pay attention that `float entries.XXX()` will be interpreted as `(float entries.XXX)()` so we have to write `float (entries.XXX())` or `float <| entries.XXX()`. Anw, I edited my answer to use `.Length` instead.

Answer (score 3):

<s>You're using `()` delimiters for what appears to be a record, but records use `{}` delimiters. Change your first pipe to this:</s>

```
(fun acc elem ->
            {
                Ask = acc.Ask + elem.Ask,
                Bid = acc.Bid + elem.Bid,
                AskVolume = acc.AskVolume + elem.AskVolume,
                BidVolume = acc.BidVolume + elem.BidVolume
            }
)
```

Then also change the second pipe as suggested in Chester Husk's answer.

**EDIT:** No, wait. The fact that you have a `let zero = new Candle()` line makes me rethink that. And you said earlier that `Candle` is a C# object. Then in that case, what you are actually trying to do is mutate the fields of your newly-created `zero` object. In that case, you need the `<-` operator. F# *deliberately* makes a distinction between the `=` and `<-` operator. The `=` operator means *equality*, and is also used in `let x = 5` because the value of `x` **cannot change** and will always be equal to 5 in the rest of that code block since `x` was not marked `mutable`. (If `x` is an object, the object might mutate its internals, but the name `x` will always refer to that object). The `<-` operator, on the other hand, is used for assignment. It looks *different* from the `=` operator because you're not promising that that value will be there forever.

So, having said that, what you actually need is to change your accumulator function to look something like this:

```
(fun acc elem ->
    acc.Ask <- acc.Ask + elem.Ask,
    acc.Bid <- acc.Bid + elem.Bid,
    acc.AskVolume <- acc.AskVolume + elem.AskVolume,
    acc.BidVolume <- acc.BidVolume + elem.BidVolume
    acc
)
```

Note how I return `acc` by writing it, by itself, on the last line. The last expression in an F# function is its return value; no `return` keyword needed.

Then your second pipe needs to pipe into a function:

```
|> (fun result ->
        result.TimeStamp <- time,
        result.Ask <- result.Ask / float entries.Count,
        result.Bid <- result.Bid / float entries.Count,
        result.AskVolume <- result.AskVolume / float entries.Count,
        result.BidVolume <- result.BidVolume / float entries.count,
        result.Integrity <- entries.Count / expectedCount
)
```

Note how I converted `entries.Count` to a `float` because I assume your `Ask` and `Bid` values are floats. If they're integers, remove that `float` conversion, but be aware that F# uses *integer* division when you're dividing integers, e.g. the value of `5 / 2` is going to be 2, not 2.5. If you wanted 2.5 you would have to divide floats, `5.0 / 2.0`.

Comment: this will work, but the solution proposed by Nghia seems to fit better as the main data object is a c# object. but thanks for proposing it, I learned something from it.

Comment: @Thomas - I was actually going to recommend Nghia's solution too, but for a different reason. My solution, which mutates the `zero` object, is closer to how C# code is normally written. Nghia's solution, which creates a new object each time, is closer to how you'd normally write F# code: immutable data that isn't changed after it's created. So his solution is better if you're trying to learn the idiomatic F# way of doing things.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying; I'm doing things in F# that take me ages vs. C# because I'm trying to learn!

Comment: @Thomas - If you're trying to learn F#, have you come across the https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ site yet? That's Scott Wlaschin's site, and it's the best resource you can find for learning more about F#. If you haven't seen it yet, bookmark it now because you'll be reading it time and again. He starts with simple material, but some of it gets quite complicated and it took me 4-5 readings to finally get my head wrapped around some of the advanced topics he presents. But he presents them so well that I eventually got it. I highly, HIGHLY recommend that site.

Comment: F# requires hard learning IMO. It’s very difficult to learn and write F# code just by looking/mimicing existing code. So, yes, learning F# by reading Scott Wlaschin’s site is the correct way.

Comment: yes, I have been reading that site, it's very very good. I grasp some of the concepts quite well since I did VHDL before and there are some parallels in the way of thinking when designing electronics, where what looks like a variable assignment is really a permanent connection, etc. I'm putting myself through it by porting some C# code I wrote to F# so I can also compare outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a stab here, but I'm going to guess that line 154 in the pipe after your fold?  If so, the problem is a bit of syntax: instead of

```
|> (....
```

you need to pipe the result of the fold *into* a function:

```
|> fun reduced -> { TimeStamp = time
                    Ask = reduced.Ask/entries.Count
                    .... }
```

using the properties of the reduced element being piped in.

Comment: no, this is unrelated; even if removing the second pipe, the errors on the first one remain.